# variable directory followed by known one

Tags: gulp

I want to copy all files from

```
/plugins/system/name/language/en—GB/*   into /language/en-GB/*
/plugins/test/whatever/language/fr-FR/* into /language/fr-FR/*
```

I have tried that

```
gulp.task('copy:plugins:lang', function () {
    return gulp.src('./plugins/**/**/language')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('language'));
});
```

But it copies the directories inside the `language` directory

```
/language/system/name/language/en—GB/* 
/language/test/whatever/language/fr-FR/*
```

I have tried to flatten() the files but then there are copied directly inside the `language` folder instead of `en-GB` or `fr-FR`.

Note that `en-GB` or `fr-FR` is variable, it could also be `pt-BR`. Using placeholders, what I am trying to achieve is copying all files like:

```
/plugins/{type}/{name}/language/{locale}/*
```

inside `/language/{locale}/*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be able to achieve what you want using `gulp-rename` and `path`. If it's safe to assume that there are no directories inside each locale directory, you could use:

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var path = require('path');

gulp.task('copy:plugins:lang', function () {
  return gulp.src('./plugins/**/language')
    .pipe(rename(function(file) {
       file.dirname = path.basename(file.dirname);
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('language'));
});
```

Otherwise, you may need a more complex transform on `file.dirname`.